# CSS Grid Container Height Covers Other Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, css-grid

I'm building a responsive CSS grid with items whose sizes match a desired aspect ratio. I've tried the padding hack among a few other techniques, but nothing has worked nearly as well for me as using JS to determine the pixel value of `1fr` for the desired number of columns and the gap size, and then applying that to the row sizing using `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(${width}px, 0))`.

Unfortunately, this approach comes with a rather nasty side effect: the parent div (`display: grid`) doesn't know the height of its own content, so it never sizes correctly. As a result, it's never able to show more than one row of the grid. The rest of the grid items display as a line just below that first row.

To fix this, I've tried setting the height of the parent to 100%, but that covers all of the other content on the page. I've tried using containers to fix the sizing, but haven't had any luck there, either. I've also tried `overflow: auto`, to no effect. If I could calculate and manually set the height of the parent div in my script, that might work, but I've not been able to find a way to do so (and also seems like a messy approach).

Is there any (good) way to do this? Here's a demo of the issue: https://codepen.io/jmindel/pen/GRoMjEw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing:

- I tried wrapping `.grid` in another div and styling that wrapper such that it has `overflow: scroll`, which fixes the height not displaying (100% is fine in this environment--it doesn't cover anything, since it's limited to the height of its block-level parent).
- I wrote a script that temporarily sets the grid's height to a very large number, finds the lowest element in the grid, and uses its position to determine the grid's height, which gives it a forced pixel height until the next resize.

A few shortcomings of this approach:

- The grid must be contained to a scrollable subcontainer, which works well for my use, but might not for others.
- The grid's height should size properly, but didn't without a forced pixel height. `min-content` and `max-content` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

when you set the `overflow: auto` it will make a scroll bar in your element to show all of the content in the specified area. then in this case it won't help you. when you set the height of an element to 100% it's height will be the same as it's parent element. I had this problem before. if you want to set the height of an element you should set the height attribute of all the parents of the parents of your element. you can use % as the unit of height and width if you want your code be responsive and don't want to calculate the exact height of elements and if not you can use other units.  try to set height with % unit for all of your parents. it helped me and I am sure it will help you too.

Comment: Thank you! This sadly doesn't seem to have made a difference, though. Because `.grid` has sibling elements, this won't work--its parent has to be the full viewport size (`100vw` x `100vh`), so `100%` doesn't make a difference there, either. I tried removing the `.root` container, but that just removes any parent height that could have been referenced (so even with `100%` height, only the first row shows).

Comment: @jmindel if you set ```height: 100%``` for the body and 100% for .root and 50% for .grid and 14% for .card it will help you. I meant the body is the parent of root and you should set the height of it. and .root is the parent of .grid and .grid is the parent of .card. if you do this every element of card class will be just the 14% of your whole grid element and your grid will be just 50% of the whole webpage. you can change this numbers to the numbers that you want but I hope it will work

Comment: This still doesn't seem to achieve the desired behavior. Having to use specific percent values is also too specific for this particular case--I'm hoping to build a completely responsive grid that still maintains a given aspect ratio. Thanks again, though!